# compile c# class using commandline

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I want to compile a C# class using the command line in Visual Studio.

In VB I can use this line:

```
vbc /t:tlibrary /out:bin/myclassdll.dll /r:system.dll /r:system.data.dll myclass.vb
```

Can I do it with C#, do I have to add something in the web.config?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you compiling from the command-line? Why not in Visual Studio itself?

Comment: I never used visaul studio as a project ,I am writing only scripts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
csc /t:tlibrary /out:bin/myclassdll.dll /r:system.dll /r:system.data.dll myclass.cs
```